# Testing to see if a inputted value is present in an array Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

So i have a small test collection that has this format...

[Sample Data](https://pastebin.com/4qAhyt3V)

I have created a simple query that returns an array with all the ids..

```
All_Ids = db.Test_Collection.find({}, {_id:1}).map(function(item){ return item._id; })
[ 98800754, 15301328, 76812898 ]
```

And i Want to take in an inputted id and check to see if that inputted value is present in the array..

here was my initial attempt..

```
> query_Figure = 98800754
98800754
> db.Test_Collection.find({query_Figure: {$in: All_Ids}})
```

I tried using the $in operator to find that specific value.. with the array and specific id to be searched as variables, but had no luck as the query returned nothing, when the value im searching for is clearly in the array

As you can tell I am a newbie and would appreciate some help in improving the query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$in` operator returns the documents in which value of the specified field is present in the array.

In your case, since `query_Figure` is not a field in any of your documents, your query returns no matching documents.

If you just want to check if the input id is present in the `All_Ids` array, then you don't need a query. Just use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
const exists = All_Ids.includes(query_Figure);
```